# What is the shortcut key or menu option to evenly space out variable/array declarations in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I usually use Textmate, which can do this by pressing option+command+right-bracket and it evenly spaces out a selection of declared variables with values. Same goes for arrays as well, it will space out the keys and their assigned values. For context check out #2 on the following [page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/essential-textmate-shortcuts-tips-and-techniques/).

I have to use Notepad++ at work and was wondering how to do the same thing via shortcut key or menu option.

Before variables/array keys are spaced out evenly.

```
$var = 'value';
$my_var = 'value';
$data = array(
    'my_key' => 'value',
    'some_other_key' => 'value'
);
```

After variables/array keys are spaced out evenly.

```
$var    = 'value';
$my_var = 'value';
$data = array(
    'my_key'        => 'value',
    'some_other_key' => 'value'
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a shortcut, but this can be down through the TextFX menu.

Select the lines that you want to align, then select `TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Line up multiple lines by (=)`.  In your case, you would select the `var` and `my_var` lines, align them, then do the same for the `my_key` and `some_other_key` lines.  Note that TextFX will trim whitespace, but it's easy to re-add with a column select for spaces before the `=` and the typical behaviour for multiline indenting.

**Edit:** Apparently, TextFX doesn't like your array.  Don't know why, but I'll look into possible solutions.

**Edit 2:** It's because a `'` was missing for `some_other_key`.